# Deciding when to extend to child tables

Tags: database-design

I have a table of entities. For example purposes, lets call them `Vehicles`: `Car`, `Boat`, `Motercycle`, etc.

I'd ideally like to place all entities in a single `Vehicles` table because a lot of related tables (`VehicleRatings`, `VehicleComments`, `VehicleHistory`, etc) are going to apply to any entity, not just one of them.

But some of the entities have a few individual properties that aren't shared with the other entity types. Right now, there is only 1 extra property for one entity, and 2 for another. I expect there might be a few more that get identified later on, but not many overall.

How do I know when it's better to create a child table for each entity type to store these individual properties, as opposed to just adding an extra column in the parent `Vehicles` table? Is there any questions I can ask myself to help determine this answer?

I am looking to optimize for query performance primarily, followed by ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a logical ERD perspective, the appropriate design is clearly the entity supertype/subtype pattern.  What you're wrestling with is how to implement this from a physical perspective.

Like a lot of data modeling issues, there is no hard and fast rule.  You are looking at a compromise.  Do you want a fair bit more complexity in your application logic and queries (supertype/subtype) or do you want the risk that your application logic might not properly enforce your constraints and that a *Car* record in your consolidated `vehicle` table might get a non-null value in the `anchor_weight` column?

The kinds of things that you should consider in deciding how to trade off these alternatives are:

- How many subtype dependent columns are there?
- How likely is it that new subtypes will be defined in the future - or that new subtype dependent columns will be needed?
- How serious would it be if inappropriate data (column values) were recorded for some records?
- Where do you stand philosophically? (e.g. "Null columns are evil", "Application-enforced constraints are evil", "1:1 relationships are evil", "Inner joins are evil", etc.)
- How many queries do I have which target only one subtype?
- Do I have any programming environment constraints which make supertype/subtype physical models harder to work with (e.g. heavy use of ORMs or simplistic tools like Access).

At the end of the day, you are going to make a practical decision based on what is most important to you.  Whatever you decide will have pros and cons - but they will be your pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into two techniques: class-table-inheritance and shared-primary-key.
These two techniques have tags that describe them over in SO.

By applying these two techniques to your case, you may end up with a simpler, yet more powerful design than the one you propose. In some cases, you can dispense with the TypeID entirely, because a join between the generalized table and the appropriate specialized table will yield precisely the objects you are looking for. In addition, because the join is on two primary keys, the join will be relatively fast.